# Stream live video from iPhone to remote server

Tags: objective-c, video, video-streaming, live-streaming

All

I am trying to create an app that start capturing the video from camera when it is launched and then starts sending the video data to the remote server in real time and keeps capturing and sending it to the server. So it is a kind of live video broadcast. Can anyone please tell me where to start? I have googled a lot but could not find any solution to this problem. Kindly help.

Comment: Did you completed this task?.Please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here:  https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

and here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Capture your video using the AV Foundation framework, and upload it to your server using HTTP streaming.

Comment: Please give me some examples to upload live video to a server

Comment: Ramkumar, did you ever find a good iOS starting example -- for iPhone?
thanks.

Comment: Any sample code please? I want to capture video from my iPhone and play the same video remotely on another device.